# next 13 and pocketbase do not return cookie on mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, pocketbase

this is my server component using server actions

```js
const result = await LoginSchema.isValid(await data)
    if (result === true) {
        try {
            const dota_resp = await pb.collection('UserTable').authWithPassword(await data.Email, await data.Password);

            if (dota_resp && await pb.collection('UserTable').authRefresh()) {
                cookies().set(pb.authStore.exportToCookie({httpOnly: true}), { secure: false })
                return {"success": JSON.stringify(pb.authStore)}
            }
            else{
                return{"failed": "something went wrong with with validation"}
            }
        }
        catch (error) {
            return { "failed": JSON.stringify(error) };
        }
    }
```

and i just manually setting authstore

```js
if (dependency.success) {
            setIsPending(false)
            const DataMutation = JSON.parse(dependency.success)
            const tok = await DataMutation.storageFallback.pocketbase_auth.token
            const mod = await DataMutation.storageFallback.pocketbase_auth.model
         
            pb.authStore.save(tok,mod)
            return router.push("/")
        }
```

im trying to access cookie from middleware

```js
if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/account')) {
    console.log(response.headers)

    
    if(await request.cookies.has("pb_auth")){
      return NextResponse.next()
    }
    else{
      return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url))
    }
}
```

im only beginner, but i think im missing something...

i tried to debug for whole day...but no result...i hope somebody could help me.